# Java, selenium: How do I check src changes in element after click and use if statement to verify it

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

[eclipse,java,selenium]
I am trying to verify with 'if statement' that the image has been pressed and the image has changed, through SRC that is changing onclick. the web element is:

```
<img name="by_Name" id="aa" src="name.png" style="width:100px" onclick="document.getElementById('aa').src='name_red.png'">
```

and my code is:

```
WebElement red = driver.findElement(By.id("aa"));
    red.click(); //now the element changes to src=name_red.png
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    String red2 = driver.findElement(By.id("aa")).getAttribute("src");

    if (red2 != "name_red2.png") {
        System.out.println("It didn't work");
    }else {
        System.out.println("Image is red now");
    }
```

I have tried with
WebElement red2 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[src='name_red.png']"));
But it cannot go to the if statement or at least I have no idea how to do it
I've also tried: if (red2 != "name_red.png") and without .png

Comment: Have you tried `"name_red2.png".equals(red2)`?

Comment: I really appreciate your answer but.... it gives me an error 'Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to String'

Comment: Have you put it in the if like this: `if ("name_red2.png".equals(red2)) {` This should work as both side are type of `String` and value comparison between two `String` objects must be done via `equals` method.

Comment: Yes I have done,\\ if ("name_red.png".equals(red2)) // but it always goes to the else option. I think the getAttribute("src") doesn't capture the name of the given src maybe that is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, that you are checking an **always false** expression in your `if` statement. Here is why:

- the `src` of the original image is `name.png`
- the `src` after the click changes to `name_red.png`
- the `if` statement chacks for `name_red2.png`, which could not appear in any of the `img` states, therefore always the `else` branch executed

In my opinion you want to check for either `if ("name_red.png".equals(red2))`, and in case it is true, everything is working, if it is not, then it didn't work, or you could check for `if ("name.png".equals(red2))`, which effectively means, that `img` still has the original value, therefore no change occurred.

Another side note: using `Thread.sleep(1000);` might effectively mean, that it will always succeed, as it leaves enough time for javascript, to do it's staff in the background. You can play with this value, to validate, that both branches of the `if-else` block is called, in case the sleeping time is small enough.

Comment: The reason I used name_red2 was to check if I can get both options but no matter what I do it always uses the else option(even with .equals()), how can I tell it's working if I can't get both results(T/F)?

Comment: If my understanding is correct, your src will be either name_red, or name, therefore it cannot be name_red2, no matter how you define it in the if statement. Try with name or name_red, not with a value, that is never ever assigned to src.